# Logstash and Flowdock integration

Tags: http, rest, https, logstash, flowdock

I'm trying to send a subset of messages to Flowdock as output from Logstash. Unfortunately, due to [this issue](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1612) I get essentially nothing back about why my messages aren't making it. Stripping down to a basic example, I see the problem even if I change my output config to the following:

```
output {
  http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "https://api.flowdock.com/v1/messages/team_inbox/API_TOKEN"
    format => "message"
    content_type => "application/json"
    message => "{\"source\":\"logstash\",\"from_address\":\"me@example.com\", \"subject\":\"Log Message\", \"content\":\"test\"}"
  }
}
```

I know, though, that output is generally working because if I add the following to output I see log messages written to the file:

```
file {
  path => "/mnt/test.log"
}
```

I also know that the http message I'm sending to Flowdock should work since

```
curl -X POST https://api.flowdock.com/v1/messages/team_inbox/API_TOKEN -d "{\"source\":\"logstash\",\"from_address\":\"me@example.com\",\"subject\":\"Log Message\",\"content\":\"test\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

results in a message being posted to the team inbox.

Are there any ways to work around this issue to determine why my output from logstash is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start debugging the issue by first sending the requests from Logstash to a service that just outputs the received request, for example [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/).

Something like:

```
output {
  http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "http://requestb.in/<created_id>"
    format => "message"
    content_type => "application/json"
    message => "{\"source\":\"logstash\",\"from_address\":\"me@example.com\",\"subject\":\"Log Message\", \"content\":\"test\"}"
  }
}
```

After you've made sure that the request Logstash is making is correct, take that request (preferably the exact data) and try to send it to Flowdock using `curl` or some other means.

At this point you should be able to tell why the request fails in either end and notify the party accordingly (i.e. open a ticket to https://logstash.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa or send an email to support@flowdock.com).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the issue. Turns out it due to a [known bug](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1776) in logstash with how it handles quotes. Became immediately obvious upon seeing the actual request it was sending.